# Downgrade iPhone 12 camera to a single lens, with an app?

Tags: iphone, camera

I think the iPhone 12 double lens camera produces images which are not artistically focused, with extra sharpness all over the image rather than a single point of focus, and too much light reducing the natural dynamics of the scene.

I have basically just downgraded to iPhone XR as a consequence as it is driving me mad. Haven't taken a good photo since I got the 12.

Otherwise I like the iPhone 12. Is there some way to "dowgrade" the camera or app? Just to use a single lens like before?

Comment: Which mode are you using when taking pictures?

Comment: If you want Pro-level better control of the camera, try the iOS app [Camera+ 2](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/camera-2/id1313580627) for US$8. As a semi-pro photographer, I find that this app really leverages the processing power of the iPhone and can assist in creating amazing photos. _Note: I'm a happy customer of LateNiteSoft S.L. and have received no monetary or other compensation for this recommendation._

Answer (score 4):

The iPhone 12 only uses one lens at a time to take a photo, so essentially what you want is already what you get.

Remember that at the bottom of the standard Camera app, you can switch between "Photo" mode and "Portrait" mode - and that with the ".5x / 1x / 2x" indicator just above, you can switch between lenses.

Perhaps it is the new lens correction feature for the Ultra Wide lens that is annoying you. You can turn that off from `Settings` in the `Camera` section where you'll find a slider for `Lens Correction`.

Comment: I think what I'm seeing is more "orange" photos, where the lighting is more even over the image, as if its been processed to add more light and sharpness. It definitely is changing the colours of the iPhone XR camera.

Comment: @apkg Halide and other camera apps allow to shoot in RAW format, without any processing. May be worth trying one of them to see whether the orange tint is a post-processing artifact or a hardware issue.

Comment: I think it may be that the XR camera doesn't capture the colours as accurately, and the "orange" is more realistic. I'm just not sure if the more realistic version is actually looking better. Maybe I just need to get used to it. I turned off "show image outside frame" which was annoying and distracting, so that might help.

Comment: The 12 is definitely muddying the whites up, making them more similar and orange, as if light has been added. I'm getting the same effect with hallide. The pure whites just can't be captured on the 12. The XR seems to get them very nicely.

Comment: Have you enabled HDR?

Comment: That can be useful in some situations, but less desirable in others. I suppose it is another thing one may vary to try to get the right effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by turning off the "true tone" in Settings -> Display and Brightness, it massively changed how the image was represented on the screen. The "oranging" effect or "over lighting" is gone, and the picture looks more natural.